# How do I read data from a binary file into an array with different file types in a field? Java

Tags: java, arrays, binaryfiles

I've tried about a hundred different methods and none of them seem to work. I'm trying to take data from a binary file, in which I've inputted data, and put it into an array with: a String, Int, Int, Int, Double, all stored into an object. More specifically, my array toolArray[] holds objects ToolItem which consists of toolName, toolID, toolQuality, toolNumberInStock, and toolPrice.

I can write the data into the binary file just fine, but I'm having troubles taking it out and putting it back into the array, for if a user exits the program and wants to come back later to fill the array again with previously inputted data (from the binary sequential .dat file).

this is how I'm putting in the data:

```
try
     {           
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("myfile.dat");
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(fout);

        System.out.println("Writing array into myfile");
        System.out.println(tools.toolArray[0].getName());
        System.out.println(tools.numberOfItems);

        for(int i=0; i<=tools.numberOfItems-1; i++)
        {
           System.out.println("Printing " + tools.toolArray[i].getName());
           out.writeUTF(tools.toolArray[i].getName());

           System.out.println("Printing " + tools.toolArray[i].getID());
           out.writeInt(tools.toolArray[i].getID());

           System.out.println("Printing " +          tools.toolArray[i].getQuality());
           out.writeInt(tools.toolArray[i].getQuality());

           System.out.println("Printing "+tools.toolArray[i].getNumberInStock());
           out.writeInt(tools.toolArray[i].getNumberInStock());

           System.out.println("Printing " + tools.toolArray[i].getPrice());
           out.writeDouble(tools.toolArray[i].getPrice());

        }

  System.out.println("Done");

  out.close();
  fout.close(); 
     }
    catch ( IOException ioe)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ioe.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
     }
```

And this is my current read() snippet, which doesn't correctly get the data:

```
try{
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("myfile.dat");
        BufferedInputStream bin = new BufferedInputStream(fin);
        DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(bin);            

        while(true)
       int x = 0;
       {

        System.out.println("Reading...");
           tools.toolArray[x].setName(din.readUTF());
           tools.toolArray[x].setID(din.readInt());
           tools.toolArray[x].setQuality(din.readInt());
           tools.toolArray[x].setNumberInStock(din.readInt());
           tools.toolArray[x].setPrice(din.readDouble());
         System.out.println(tools.toolArray[x].getName()+tools.toolArray[x].getID()+
         tools.toolArray[x].getQuality()+tools.toolArray[x].getNumberInStock()+tools.toolArray[x].getPrice());
     x++;
      }

     }
     catch(EOFException eofe)
     {
        System.out.println("File read");
     }
    catch ( IOException ioe)
     {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ioe.toString(), "Error, cannot read from file", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(1);
     }
```

Any ideas? Just for a flow of how data is supposed to go, it's:
open program > open file > put in data into array from a separate JFrame window > close file > close program > open program, fresh array > fill fresh array with data from file > keep inputting data from where you left off last time

Comment: 'Having trouble' is not a problem description. Your I/O code looks OK at a quick glance. You need to initialize `x` before the loop, of course, and increment it at the end of the loop.

Comment: Yeah I realize now I messed that up, still didn't fix it however. The code doesn't read properly or insert into the array like how it's supposed to still.

Comment: And that isn't a problem description either. Try again. Would you accept this as a problem report from a customer?

Comment: The problem is when I close the program, and re-fill the array with previous data from binary file, it keeps the numbers correct but the toolName becomes null. Something in the code is preventing the name specifically from being read, but the whole thing works as long as I don't close out of the program.

Comment: 'Becomes null' is no more a problem description than anything else you've posted here, and there is no `toolName` variable in this code.

Comment: the toolName value literally becomes "null". I don't know how else you want me to put it. The numbers stay the correct numbers, but the name changes to a null value, And toolName isn't included because it's part of a different abstract class, and people on this site don't have time to look through 4 different programs

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `x = 0` before the loop, not inside it, and increment it at the bottom of the loop.